# Fixing a NullReferenceException in an AWS Lambda C# API

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda

So I followed the instructions out of one of the articles I read on AWS Lambda C# API did the conversion, pulled the swagger data to setup the API Gateway path and I keep getting this error

```
{
  "errorType": "NullReferenceException",
  "errorMessage": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
  "stackTrace": [
    "at Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.APIGatewayProxyFunction.MarshallRequest(InvokeFeatures features, APIGatewayProxyRequest apiGatewayRequest, ILambdaContext lambdaContext)",
    "at Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.AbstractAspNetCoreFunction`2.FunctionHandlerAsync(TREQUEST request, ILambdaContext lambdaContext)",
    "at EycLambda.LambdaFunctionHandler.FunctionHandlerAsync(APIGatewayProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext lambdaContext)",
    "at lambda_method2(Closure , Stream , ILambdaContext , Stream )",
    "at Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport.Bootstrap.UserCodeLoader.Invoke(Stream lambdaData, ILambdaContext lambdaContext, Stream outStream) in /src/Repo/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport/Bootstrap/UserCodeLoader.cs:line 145",
    "at Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport.HandlerWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<GetHandlerWrapper>b__0(InvocationRequest invocation) in /src/Repo/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport/Bootstrap/HandlerWrapper.cs:line 56",
    "at Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport.LambdaBootstrap.InvokeOnceAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /src/Repo/Libraries/src/Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport/Bootstrap/LambdaBootstrap.cs:line 176"
  ]
}
```

i ended finding a stackoverflow saying I had to add a bit code to the EntryPoint

```
protected internal async Task<APIGatewayProxyResponse> FunctionHandlerAsync(APIGatewayProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext lambdaContext)
    {
        return await base.FunctionHandlerAsync(request, lambdaContext);
    }
```

that cause a LambdaSerializationError which I found another stackflow saying I just needed to add this bit of code
[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer))]

now Im back to the NullReferenceException and I'm a little lost on what I'm missing.

this is the endpoint I'm testing out on the API

````
        {
            List<EycDAL.Models.Page> pageResponse = null;
            try
            {
                pageResponse = manager.getAllPages();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                pageResponse = null;
            }
            return Json(pageResponse);
        }```


included in the post
````

Comment: Here is the article I originally followed to start this undertaking 
https://codemag.com/Article/2008041/Transform-Your-ASP.NET-Core-API-into-AWS-Lambda-Functions

Answer (score 0):

I followed the same path and implemented the lambda with that article. For my "standard" lambdas that expose apis I had no problem, but for the one I was trying to trigger by a scheduled CloudWatch Event (EventBridge), I had the same issue. I solved it by adding in the `LambdaEntryPoint.cs` (that you should have if you followed the article and created the Lambda from the VS Template):

```cs
public override async Task<APIGatewayProxyResponse> FunctionHandlerAsync(APIGatewayProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext lambdaContext)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Finally here!!");
    var response = new APIGatewayProxyResponse
    {
        StatusCode = 200,
        Body = "Correctly executed!",
        Headers = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Content-Type", "text/plain" } }
    };
    return response;
}
```

Hope it helps.

---

Edit:

the Lambda handler function is defined in the `serverless.template` file of your project (in my case it was the `FunctionHandlerAsync` method of `LambdaEntryPoint` class - that is actually a virtual method implemented in `Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer.AbstractAspNetCoreFunction` class)